# Seeking within MP3 file

Tags: mp3, decoder

I am working on the development of driving software for the hardware implementation by [these people](https://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/~nicola/mpeg.html). The decoder works properly in overall, but I am struggling making it starting playing the sound at the middle. I suspect that it is common feature of the MP3 decoders as they must have some history of data in order to properly construct current sound (I am not that skilled in MPEG, however have an idea of some basics).
The problem is that this decoder is a black box, and any deepening in its code is an enormous time and effort.
I empirically found out that the sound garbage, when starting somewhere in the middle, happens in no more that 1 (one) seconds after start with file @ 320 kbps and 44100 sampling rate. I am actually ok to mute decoder for a second (while it gathers/decodes proper required data for further playback), and then unmute it to continue playback.

I did search on the internet for the matter, did not find anything useful. Tried to invalidate first frames by corrupting frame headers (the easiest that could be done without going into the MP3 headers/data), made things even worse.

Questions:

1. is there any body of knowledge of how players perform seek in MP3 files and keep non-corrupt sound?
2. Is my action plan seem valid - mute for 1 second while decoder plays garbage? Is there any way to (easily) calculate the time I must mute output for?

Update: just tried on another file @ 128 kbps/48k and maximal garbage time to be about 2 seconds... I can not believe that decoder with so limited resources - input buffer used is 2 kB with some intermediate working buffers, in total must be not more than 36 kB - can keep the history for 2 seconds, or decoder is having problems finding the sync word in the stream... and thus my driver needs to figure out the frame start (by finding out sync word, reading frame header, calculating frame size, and looking after the frame to contain another sync word).

Answer (score 0):

I've found workarounds. The difficulty was that there are actually two problems overlaying each other, but was easy to cope with having structured approach.

1. The decoder is having issues getting the first sync word of the stream, and works very well when the first bytes supplied to it are FF FB or FF FA. All other bytes - in the middle of the frame - with very high probability, cause *major* sound corruption, until decoder catches correct sync. Thus I designed the code seeking to the next frame start after the seek point, checking that this is actual start of the frame by calculating frame size and looking at the next frame to contain FFFB/FA.
2. Having fixed the problem 1 I have had *minor* corruption left from the decoder starting decoding the frame without historical data. I have solved it by muting the decoder for the first 4 buffering transactions.

Major corruption still happens, but is rare, and it seems that nature of corruption depends on what was in the decoder buffers (not only Huffman input buffer, but other intermediate buffers) before the decoder is instructed to start. My hardware performs clear of the input buffers to 0 when decoder is in reset state, but it seems to be not enough (or just incorrect)...

The decoder itself is a kind of PoC (proof of concept) work, a student term with the aim to prove that they were able to make it; the package is having test bench code, but lacks low level documentation/comments in the code, and is not ready for field implementation and production. In general the fact that it worked for me at all (almost) out of the box makes the honor to the developers and is a mark of high quality of their work. I have reviewed and tried several published projects for MP3 decoders for silicon implementation (FPGA) and concluded that this one is the best available. In addition, the license they provide their work on is generous one.

**Update:** my research have shown that the most problem lies not in the input buffer (however it is possible to improve the situation by uploading 528 bytes of historical data to the decoder's buffer so that it would be able to grab main data from previous frame), but in the internal *state* of the decoder. Its documentation says:

> To reduce resource usage, part of the RAM for buffering the intermediate data is also shared with Huffman decoding as bit reservoir ...

thus it is a contents of the reservoir and intermediate computed data affecting the decoding. I have confirmed it by starting various set of frames in different sequence, and if set of frames are played in different sequence, nature of garbage changes, or garbage may simply not appear.

Thus, unfortunately, my conclusion: it is not possible to properly seek using this decoder as is. I even do not think it is possible to "fake" playback (to quickly "play" the file till the needed point in buffers) as all three clocks are tied to each other.

I will keep my "best tested" implementation, with the notes on the quality.

**Update 2:** I was wrong, it is possible to seek softly, but to mitigate the sound corruption (yes, I am still unsure if I fixed it completely) I had to find another deficiency in the decoder: it is related to timing, decoder assumes that further data is always available in the buffer, while it may not be there yet. (It is actually clear from the test bench code supplied within the IP - the way data was replenished during QA and testing). In the cases I caught the corruption, first frames in the first part of the input buffer RAM were not decoded properly, skipped, and decoder quickly skips to second part of the RAM, assuming new data is there, however driving hardware is not ready yet fetching required data and putting this data into the second part of decoder's buffer RAM, thus corruption persisted for quite a long time with decoder looping skipping "invalid" frames until it catches correct image of the frame and normalizes its pace through the buffer.

Now the solution:

1. play (almost) 5 frames of silence through decoder before unmuting it. This will ensure all decoder's internal buffers are purged. It will not take much time, however requires some coding;
2. introduce a possibility to set huffman's decoder starting pointer `readptr` (in *huffctl.v*) after reset into the value other than 0. It will give the flexibility to have some history data uploaded into the decoder's buffer and start huffman decoder from the middle of the buffer rather than from its very start;
3. calculate the position to seek to, it calculates relatively easily for MPEG-1 Layer-3: duration=(filesize-ID3size)/(bitrate/8*1000), newPosition=ID3size+seekTime*(bitrate/8*1000). Duration is needed to check that position to seek to fits into the play time, alternatively newPosition can be used to check against file size. These forumlas do not take into account older tag versions appearing at the end of the file, but they are usually not more than 128 bytes, thus a kind of negligible for timing calculation relative to average MP3 sound file size; it also assumes CBR (VBR will require completely different way, requiring more power and data I/O for accurate seeking). Funny enough I found web pages with *incorrect* duration calculation formula, thus beware posts by ignorant people with cool job titles;
4. Seek to the calculated position, find next frame from this position on, calculate frame size, and ensure that there's next valid frame at that distance. New pointer will point to this next frame found at the distance;
5. find out the main_data_begin lookback pointer of the frame now being pointed to at step 4. Decrease the new pointer by this value so that pointer points within previous frame to the start of the main data for the current frame - it will be a pointer for the decoder data start. Note that it will fail if main data begins in more than one frame back (removal of headers of previous frame(s) will be required for proper operation);
6. fill decoder's buffer starting pointer identified in step 5, and set decoder's decoding start pointer to the one identified in step 4. While the implementation assumes you fill buffer in halves, do it different from the start: fill the whole buffer instead of just a first half. For this, after reset, set idle bit, check for data request, reset idle bit, perform two 1024 byte transfers to the decoder's buffer (effectively filling it completely), and then set idle bit, then reset it, and then set it again;
7. after performing step 7 continue normally replenishing 1024 bytes per decoder's request.

Employing this plan I had zero sound corruption cases. As you see it requires some changes to Verilog, but it must be easy if you know basics or hardware, know Verilog amd can perform reverse engineering.